# DOM elements are not present when use change page in jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, dom

My project structure looks like:

[image]

I use multi page (single HTML divided into pages [data-role="page"] ) to develop mobile application. In the above image, script files are in js folder and jquery related plugins are in lib folder like wise.

Refer this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aravinth/2w0j0gpp/2/)  for my code(this works fine).

My problem is when login button is clicked then it needs to show the view page but it won't show the DOM.

My **index.html**:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">
<script src="lib/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/handlebars-v1.3.0.js"></script>
<script src="login.js"></script>
<script src="view.page.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="loginpage">
        <script id="login-tmpl" type="x-handlebars-template">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Login Page</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input type="text" value="a">
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" value="">
                </div>

                   <button id="loginBtn">Login</button>

            </div><!-- /content -->
        </script>
    </div>
    <!-- /login page end -->
    <div data-role="page" id="viewpage">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1> View Page</h1>
        </div>
        <input type="text" value=" view pager shown">
    </div>
```

and **login.js**:

```
$(document).on("pageinit","#loginpage",function(){
    $.mobile.page.prototype.options.domCache = true;
    var source = $("#login-tmpl").html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

    $("#loginpage").html(template);
    $("#loginpage").trigger("pagecreate");    
});

$(document).on("click","#loginBtn",function(){
    alert("btn clicked");
    $.mobile.page.prototype.options.domCache = true;
    $.mobile.changePage("#viewpage");
});
```

and **view.page.js** is:

```
$(document).on("pageshow","#viewpage",function(){
    alert("i am view page");
    $.mobile.page.prototype.options.domCache = true;
    $("#viewpage").trigger("pagecreate");      
});
```

**NOTE:**
Without using lib,js folders(all script and plugins inside www folder) it works fine(means load the view page DOM's)